# Merging a Named Sheet from Multiple Excel Workbooks, copying the headers only once, with a source range that is variable

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I'm currently trying to run. The code works somewhat but the headers are copied from every worksheet and there is a significant gap in row count between where the data from the next file is copied. For example first file has 3600 row, the next data is copied in row 13,000. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    ' Create a new workbook and set a variable to the first sheet.
    Set SummarySheet = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

    ' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
    FolderPath = "C:\Desktop\Files to Combine\"

    ' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
    NRow = 1

    ' Call Dir the first time, pointing it to all Excel files in the folder path.
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")

    ' Loop until Dir returns an empty string.
    Do While FileName <> ""
        ' Open a workbook in the folder
        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)


        ' Set the source range to be A1 through BH and the last row.
        ' Modify this range for workbooks.
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:BH" & LastRow)

        ' Set the destination range to start at column A and
        ' be the same size as the source range.
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("A1" & NRow)
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        ' Copy over the values from the source to the destination.
        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

        ' Increase NRow so that we know where to copy data next.
        NRow = NRow + DestRange.Rows.Count

        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes.
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False

        ' Use Dir to get the next file name.
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Call AutoFit on the destination sheet so that all
    ' data is readable.
    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: change `Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("A1" & NRow)` to `Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("A" & NRow)`. You are adding a leading 1 to every `NRow` variable. So 1 becomes 11. 100 becomes 1100.

Answer (score 0):

For row count issue, heed @ScottHoltzman's comments. Another issue too is a large amount of cells can be empty but are still in the used range as only their contents were cleaned but formatting remained. You may need to delete such cells from workbooks not just clear contents.

And to avoid repeat headers, condition the first file to bring over headers and all else to begin on row 2.

```
i = 1                            ' INITIALIZE AN INT/LONG VARIABLE
Do While FileName <> ""
    '...
    If i = 1 Then
       Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:BH" & LastRow)
    Else
       Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:BH" & LastRow)
    End If
    '...
    i = i + 1                    ' INCREMENT VARIABLE
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
```